# Inline function for the jQuery open event

Tags: jquery, dialog

I have a cshtml page, where in i have two buttons with different id's, but with same class. When i click on either of the button, same dialog will be opened with corresponding information based on the id of the button.

```
$('.class').click(function(){
    $('divDialog').dialog().('open');  
});
```

The above code was used to trigger open event of the jquery dialog. And, the Open event of the jquery dialog is as follows:

```
open: function(){

}
```

But, i need to differentiate the click event based on the button which triggered the event, to display the corresponding information in the jquery dialog. As I have used the class of the buttons, I need to pass the id of the control to open event of the jquery dialog. Is that possible?

Or else, is there any way to have a inline open event for the jquery dialog, as like,

```
$('divDialog').dialog().('open', function(){});
```

Kindly give your inputs for the problem.

Thanks
Manikandan J

Answer (score 0):

You can create a variable pointing to current button element and use it inside `open` event listener(Assuming you are initializing `dialog` somewhere before:

```
var currentButton;

$('divDialog').dialog({    //Here we initialize dialog and immediatelly close it
    open: function() {
        //Here you can use `currentButton` variable
    },
    close: function() {
        currentButton = null;    //Clear `currentButton` when dialog is closed
    }
}).dialog("close");

$('.class').click(function(){
    currentButton = this;

    $('divDialog').dialog('open');  
});
```

Or you can initialize `dialog` right inside click event listener:

```
$('.class').click(function(){
    var button = this;

    $('divDialog').dialog({
        open: function(){
            //Here you can use `button` variable
        }
    });
});
```